# I need to get first name and birth date of the user that uses my Page Tab on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I need to get first name (maybe last too) and date of birth (year is enough) of user viewing my app (Page Tab) on facebook.

I'm using the Facebook SDK PHP, using the link from the Facebook developer's page. I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getSession() in /home/szymadjg/public_html/facebook/index.php on line 18

Comment: for birthday, you need to get user permission 'user_birthday' http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

congrats on your first Facebook app.  Secondly, let's step back to basics.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/ for a tutorial on how to get started.  Also see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/.  Please note that for the `signed_request`, it will work differently between a iFramed application and a page tab app (like what you're making).  I know I spent a couple days learning about the differences.  That signed request will contain an access token for your app to call into the graph API to get the user's name and birth date (you will need to request `user_birthday` additional permissions).

Comment: Sorry for this, but I don't have much time to studying this. Can you show mi what to do???? Please

Comment: All I could do is copy and paste from those tutorials...I really couldn't add much of benefit to what is currently documented. Sorry.